# Specifying native Android APK permissions

Tags: android, permissions, apk

When I install my app on an AVD (or a real device), it shows the requested permissions as "Storage - modify/delete SD card contents" and "Phone calls - read phone state and identity"

However, I don't need these permissions and have not requested them in my AndroidManifest.xml (see below).

What is causing these permissions to be requested, and how can I prevent the permissions being required?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="my.App"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="com.co.my.App">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

There may not be enough information here to diagnose the problem - any information about how required permissions are specified / calculated would be appreciated

Comment: It shouldn't happen. Have you tried to uninstall an reinstall? Tried to clean the project? Are you sure you're looking at the right Maninfest? You might have multiples sheets from multiple projects opened and maybe look at the wrong one, it happens...

Comment: No, I mean if I execute grep -r "uses-" . there are literally no matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These permissions were not required in the first release of Android.

In order to avoid apps developed against that breaking on subsequent release devices where they are required to perform associated actions, they are automatically added at install time if the AndroidManifest.xml does not have a `uses sdk` tag declaring a version subsequent to their introduction (which would be 3, if I recall correctly).

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target